# How to store a Rating

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im currently working on a website that display pictures, and those pictures will have a 5 stars rating.

The question is, where, or how can I store the rating of each pic.

Example: Subject 1 gives 4 stars to the picture( How can I store that rating)
         Subject 2 gives 2 stars to the picture.

So the picture will have a 3 Start rating

Im currently using HTML, CSS, PHP, and MYSQL.

Is there a way of storing in MYSQL the rating?

Hope you can help me.

Comment: You really have to try something yourself. This question is too broad, and Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: read through  http://megarush.net/5-star-rating-system-with-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

Save the rating so:

```
INSERT INTO ranting (picture_id, user_id, ranting) VALUE (1, 1, 5);
```

And to get the average, do as follows:

```
SELECT AVG(ranting) AS ranting, COUNT(ranting) AS total FROM ranting WHERE picture_id=1;
```

Comment: Awesome that will work perfectly Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for the rating with the image id (whatever you call the identifier), the score of each rating and the user id (if there is a limit to how often each user is allowed to rate distinct images). Add a datetime field if you want to track the ratings by date.

To get the aggregated rating just send a query to the database in which you group by the image id and use AVG() on the rating-column.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a `users` `table`:

> users(id, username, password)

and let's suppose you have a `pictures` `table`:

> pictures(id, caption, src)

Also, let's suppose you have a `ratings` `table`:

> ratings(id, user_id, picture_id, value)

When a picture is shown to a user, you need to determine whether the user has already rated the picture:

```
select 1
from ratings
where user_id = 5 and picture_id = 10
```

(assuming that 5 is the id of the user logged in and 10 is the id of the picture)

if the query returns a record, then the user has already rated the picture and he/she should no longer able to rate it. If the query does not return a record, then the user has not rated the picture yet, therefore he/she should be able to rate it.

When a user attempts to rate a picture, you need to `insert` the rating if and only if the user has not rated that picture yet. Assuming that user with the id value of 5 attempts to rate a picture with the id of 10 with a rating of 2:

```
insert into ratings(user_id, picture_id, value)
select 5, 10, 2
from ratings
where not exists (select 1
                  from ratings
                  where user_id = 5 and picture_id = 10)
```

When you need to load the rating of the picture having the id of 10, you need to do the following selection:

```
select avg(value) as picture_rating
from ratings
where picture_id = 10
```

If you do not want to calculate this average each time, then you can create the following `table`:

> aggregated_ratings(id, picture_id, value)

and whenever a new rating is added check whether there is already an aggregated rating, like this:

```
select 1
from aggregated_ratings
where picture_id = 10
```

If you get a record, then

```
update aggregated_ratings
set value = (select avg(value)
             from ratings
             where picture_id = 10)
where picture_id = 10;
```

If not, then

```
insert into aggregated_ratings(picture_id, values)
select 10, avg(value)
from ratings
where picture_id = 10
```

Note that insertion/update to `aggregated_ratings` should be executed after the insertion to `ratings` was executed.